# Can I install fonts in Windows 7 in my private user's space?

Tags: windows-7, installation, fonts

Mac OS X and some Linux distros allow me to non-administratively install fonts in my own userspace (e.g. in OS X: `~/Library/Fonts/`).

Can I do the same in Windows (specifically Windows 7)?

Comment: Thought you can't. But some programs may use font files (if they are able to do) - Windows allows to register font file in per-application basis.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/118025/using-custom-fonts-without-administrator-rights

Answer (score 1):

No. Windows 7 (and Windows in general) does not have the same concept as System vs User fonts. There is really only the global font folder available to all users and the system.

Andi Mohr [mentioned this question](https://superuser.com/questions/118025/using-custom-fonts-without-administrator-rights) which can help you work around the Administrator requirements for installing fonts if that is your issue.