# How can one use a .tff font in Word 2013 as unpriviliged user without PowerShell?

Tags: windows, fonts, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013, truetype-fonts

I would like to use a font I have available as a .ttf file for one of my texts.

The obvious way to do that is to install the font system wide and use it that way.

Is there a different path one could take when administrative privileges are not available (the execution of PowerShell scripts is blocked too)?
It feels like that should be possible.

edit: I haven't yet gotten the PowerShell method linked [here](https://superuser.com/a/1306464/982340) to work.
I would like to keep the question up, as I am hoping for a method within Word, to bundle the .ttf with or at least open it for specific documents.
*(along the lines of: Format -> Fonts -> add Font file to document)*
edit2: Sadly the execution of PowerShell scripts is unavailable on the machines in question. `UnauthorizedAccess`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install fonts in Windows without admin rights?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185779/is-it-possible-to-install-fonts-in-windows-without-admin-rights)

Comment: This question sadly has to be: How do I do that without admin rights and without the PowerShell :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts without administrator rights?](https://superuser.com/questions/118025/using-custom-fonts-without-administrator-rights)

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? In Windows 10 17704 and above just right click > install. And UnauthorizedAccess doesn't mean that you don't have powershell. You just need to run [`set-executionpolicy remotesigned`](https://superuser.com/q/106360/241386) to allow script execution, or if it's not possible just copy all the lines in the script and paste directly onto Powershell, since you always have rights to execute commands

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a font permanently under a non-admin account, but you can do it temporarily (for the current session). Check Pabru's answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1306464/980675).

P.S. OK, if PowerShell doesn't work, this is the corresponding MSVC code:

```c
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2)   {
        std::cout << "Usage: RegFont <font-file>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    AddFontResource(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Try running [RegFont32](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vnsj89m9qjz9vd/RegFont32.exe?dl=1) `<font-file>` or [RegFont64](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qz047wvpz4lcesj/RegFont64.exe?dl=1) `<font-file>`

Comment: I am getting a FullyQualifiedError by the name of UnauthorizedAccess as PowerShell execution is blocked.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that. Try compiled version then, it should work.

Comment: `You can't install a font permanently under a non-admin account` in fact [you can](https://superuser.com/a/1345896/241386)