# Use Font in VBA without admin rights

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, vba, fonts, administrator

I'm a newbie and I'm very happy to use this platform, to ask you some question.

I'm trying to work in Excel with a font (.ttf) which is not installed in Windows. I can't install it, cause I don't have admin rights. Is there any other way, to load the font in my VBA code?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please take the quick [tour] to know how this community works. If one answer helps you then [accept it](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the green checkmark to let people know the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an older version of Windows then there are various tricks and tools to load a font without admin rights like [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/) or [WinFontsForAll](https://apps.gorilla.moe/winfontsforall/).
More detailed information can be find in this question [Using custom fonts without administrator rights?](https://superuser.com/q/118025/241386)

If you're using Windows 10 build 17704 and up then you already have the ability to install fonts without admin rights

---

If you're allowed to use Win32 API then you can also load the font yourself from VBA using [`AddFontResource()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew)

Another way that you can try is *embedding the font in the Excel file*. By default [only Word and PowerPoint support that](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-fonts-in-word-or-powerpoint-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc) but there's a workaround provided by MS

> ## What about embedding fonts in Excel?
>
> Excel doesn't have the Embed Fonts feature. Therefore, you can't embed a font directly into an Excel file like you can with Word or PowerPoint, but there is workaround: Embed a font in a Word document, as described above, then copy data from an Excel workbook into the Word document, and finally apply the embedded font to the data you copied in from Excel. (You must keep the Excel data in the Word document for the font to remain as it is.)

However note that **not all fonts are embeddable**

> Not all fonts are licensed so that they can be embedded. If a font can be embedded, it will increase the file size of your document by approximately the size of the TrueType font (.ttf) file.
>
> NOTE: Some fonts treat normal, bold, italic, and bold-italic as separate font .ttf files. In this case, the file size of your document is larger when you use bold and italic formatting than it is if you do not.
>
> If a font does not have a bold, italic, or bold-italic version, Windows generates bold or italic from the core font. In this case, the file size increases when you use bold or italic formatting.
>
> Licensing rights for font embedding determine how the font may be embedded in the document.
>
> [How to embed a TrueType font in a document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/290952/how-to-embed-a-truetype-font-in-a-document)

To check if the font is embeddable click on its name in Control Panel > Fonts

[image]

See also [Embedding Fonts in Excel](https://excel.tips.net/T001969_Embedding_Fonts_in_Excel.html)

---

That said, depending on what you're trying to do it may not need to install a font at all. For example to get a barcode you can draw them with VBA. No external font is necessary. See [Create code128 barcode without installing font?](https://superuser.com/q/1284888/241386). You can even go further by writing a font renderer in VBA, although that's not recommended

Comment: +1 well written. :)

Comment: +1 really great!

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to work with fonts, they have to be registered by the system, and that requires one to install them.

It is possible to view fonts that are not installed, but if you want to set a font, it will query the installed fonts,so you have to have the font installed in order to change the font to your new font.

Comment: but you can [install fonts without admin rights](https://superuser.com/q/118025/241386)

Comment: @phuclv only AFTER you set the proper permissions, which requires administrative rights. Its a chicken in the egg scenario.

Comment: no, there are various solutions to temporarily load a font, and in newer builds of Windows 10 users can install fonts for their own. See [Using custom fonts without administrator rights?](https://superuser.com/q/118025/241386)

Comment: @phuclv sounds like a perfect answer to me. Why don't you write one? I'll happily upvote your answer. It has been years since I tried to do what OP does and it didn't work then, I'm happily wrong if it works now though.

Comment: I thought that the link would help. But after I got some idea I've decided to write an answer